# Merge WebPack config in Vue CLI Service 3

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm looking for to set 'basePath' to all scripts and link imported in final .html file, created by `vue build`

Then i need to deploy the dist folder in a jetty servlet. The servlet is mapped at '/ui/' path. After deploying, at url `http://localost:8086/ui` the main file is well served. The problem is that all js and css files have relative-to-file path, like `<script .. src='/js/main.js'></script>`

The request fails because the right path should be `'/ui/js.main.js'.`

Is there any way to say to webpack the base path to prepend to these files?
I tried with `vue.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        build: {
            assetsPublicPath: '/ui/'
        },
        assetsPublicPath: '/ui/',
        output: {
            publicPatch: '/ui/'
        }
    },
}
```

It does not work, what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem.

Project structure:

```
- src
  - main.js
  - ...
- package.json
- vue.config.js
```

I was launching build command from inside src directory, so vue.config.js was not considered.

However the correct solution for me was:

```
const DEV_MODE = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
     output: {
        publicPath: DEV_MODE ? '' : '/ui/'

     }
   }
}
```